# Can't find package BLT

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I am having a problem of getting BLT to work with Tcl/TK. I installed BLT library for TCL/TK but when i try running a tcl program to plot a graph, it keeps giving me an error saying "can't find package BLT". In my program I have already included:

```
package require BLT
```

I also appended the BLT part to my environmental variable on my windows operating system 32 bit but it still doesn't work.

Please what do i need to do?

Answer (score 1):

To make that work, the *directory* containing the BLT package needs to be on the `auto_path`. Specifically, the directory that contains the directory containing the `pkgIndex.tcl` file (so `/foo/bar` if you put the package so that it's index file is `/foo/bar/BLT/pkgIndex.tcl`) needs to be there (as Tcl looks in the directories listed and *one* level down). That global variable is a Tcl list of places to search; you might need to put:

```
lappend auto_path /foo/bar
```

at the beginning of your script, prior to any `package require` statements. (OK, switch `/foo/bar` for the real path, and use braces around it if the directory/path-element has spaces in it, as per usual Tcl quoting rules.)