# tcl can't find package even though file is in auto_path directory

Tags: package, tcl

on windows 7, tcl 8.6.4.

My repo.tcl and region.tcl files are both in c:\sites\vive

repo is a package:

```
package provide repo 1.0

namespace eval ::repo {}
namespace eval ::repo::create{}

proc ::repo::create {} {...} ...
```

region.tcl wants access to the procs in repo.tcl so it looks like this:

```
#source ./repo.tcl <---------old method, want to replace with package require
lappend auto_path [pwd] ;#<--puts c:\sites\vive in the autopath so package can find it.

package require repo 1.0 ;#<--tried this with out version number as well. same result.

::repo::create

...
```

I always get this error:

> can't find package repo 1.0

Both of these sites have suggested I use the lappend auto_path
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44992/package-require-xxxx-tcl
[Can't find package BLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24149327/cant-find-package-blt)

What am I doing wrong? thanks!

Comment: I even tried: set auto_path "$auto_path [pwd]" that gave me the same result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to generate the `pkgIndex.tcl` file using `pkg_mkIndex`

```
% pkg_mkIndex -verbose [pwd] repo.tcl
successful sourcing of repo.tcl
packages provided were {repo 1.0}
processed repo.tcl
% lappend auto_path [pwd]
C:/Dinesh/Backup/cmder/vendor/msysgit/lib/tcl8.5 C:/Dinesh/Backup/cmder/vendor/msysgit/lib C:/Users/dsivaji/Desktop/delete
%
%
%
% package require repo
1.0
```

Have a look at the man page [pkg_mkIndex](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/pkgMkIndex.htm) for more information.

Comment: Strictly, you don't need to use `pkg_mkIndex`. It's just convenient.

Comment: @DonalFellows : `pkgIndex.tcl` is needed anyway. An index file which has the package information should be placed in the `auto_path` location. We are using `pkg_mkIndex` procedure to ease our  job.  Correct me Sir, if I'm wrong.